# xlim reactive in contourplot whit shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new tiping R code and I try to get a reactive contourplot with shiny but I can not do this:
The code for server is:

```
library(shiny)
library(latticeExtra)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  grid<-expand.grid(a = seq(10, 15, 0.1),b = seq(50, 150,10))
  grid$c=grid$a*grid$b/100

output$y<-renderPlot(contourplot( c ~  a + b, data= grid ,cuts = 20, label = TRUE,
                    xlim = c( input$Min_a, input$Max_a), ylim= c(input$Min_b,input$Max_b)))

})
```

For UI

```
library(shiny)
library(latticeExtra)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("Min_a","Enter Minimum a:",""),
      textInput("Max_a","Enter Maximum a:",""),
      textInput("Min_b","Enter Minimum b:",""),
      textInput("Max_b","Enter Maximum b:","")

                ),

    mainPanel(

      plotOutput("y")
    )
  )
))
```

Dont work. I try put de lim with a number and work but that is not what I try to do. Modification in server look like this:

```
output$y<-renderPlot(contourplot( TAzH ~  rto + TCH, data= grid ,cuts = 20, label = TRUE,
                                  xlim = c(10,15), ylim= c(50,130)))
```

Can anyone help me please. Thank you in advance.
Sorry because my english is very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the xlim and ylim to integers (they are coming as strings from the UI, then it will work). Your input to the contourPlot needs to be dynamic. Also, have some default values in the UI inputs:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$y<-renderPlot({
      grid <- expand.grid(a = seq(as.integer(input$Min_a), as.integer(input$Max_a), 0.1),b = seq(as.integer(input$Min_b), as.integer(input$Max_b,10)))
      grid$c = grid$a*grid$b/100
      #contourplot(c ~  a + b, data= grid, cuts = 20, label = TRUE, xlim=c(10,15), ylim=c(50,150,10))
      contourplot(c ~  a + b, data= grid, cuts = 20, label = TRUE,
                                      xlim = c(as.integer(input$Min_a), as.integer(input$Max_a)), 
                                      ylim= c(as.integer(input$Min_b), as.integer(input$Max_b)))
    })

})

library(shiny)
library(latticeExtra)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("Min_a","Enter Minimum a:","10"),
      textInput("Max_a","Enter Maximum a:","15"),
      textInput("Min_b","Enter Minimum b:","50"),
      textInput("Max_b","Enter Maximum b:","150")

    ),

    mainPanel(

      plotOutput("y")
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sandipan.